# Как запретить обновления содержимого QListView в автоматическом режиме?

Tags: c++, qt, mvc

При соединении модели данных `QAbstractTableModel` к `QListView` данные обновляются автоматически (постоянно вызывается функция `data`).

Как можно самостоятельно управлять этим процессом?

Answer (score 0):

Функция `data` вызывается не постоянно, а при щелчке мышью на соответствующий элемент `QListView` и при подаче сигнала [`QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged). Следовательно, если вы хотите, чтобы представление прочитало новые данные, нужно отправить этот сигнал.

```
emit dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(rowCount(), columnCount()));
```

Этот код заставит представление полностью перечитать все данные. Если нужно обновить только определённый участок данных, подставьте соответствующие индексы "правый-верхний" и "левый-нижний".

Comment: [Вот вам код](https://pastebin.com/mKLr7wZp). Можете посмотреть когда вызывается метод `data`. Это происходит далеко не только при клике и `dataChanged`. Сворачивание/разворачивание окна, изменение размера, перелет курсора над списком, пролистывание списка. Все это, и возможно многое другое, заставляет представление запрашивать данные из модели

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, к сожалению, документация молчит на предмет того, когда именно представления запрашивают данные. Нам остаётся только догадываться.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понимаю непосредственно метод `data` вызывает не само представление, а делегат. Вы можете унаследовать свой собственный делегат от [`QAbstractItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html) или [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html). 
И установить его в представление при помощи метода [`QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate).

PS: Спасибо разработчикам Qt за <strike>наше счастливое детство</strike> соблюдение S.O.L.I.D.